# How to set minimum margins in JPGraph?

Tags: php, jpgraph

How can I set minimum (or none) margins on my chart?

This is what I have now:

[image]

And this is what I want in result:

[image]

So the results should be with no margins (or minimal only).

This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once 'jpgraph/jpgraph.php';
require_once 'jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php';
require_once 'jpgraph/jpgraph_plotline.php';        

$graph = new Graph(600,600);
$graph->SetMargin(40, 10, 10, 0);
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$theme_class=new UniversalTheme();
$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

$line = new LinePlot(range(5,25));
$line->SetWeight(1);
$line->SetLegend("test");
$graph->Add($line);

$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(true);

$graph->title->hide();

$graph->xaxis->Hide();

$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

$graph->legend->hide();

$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing graph theme helped:

```
$this->graph->graph_theme=null;
```

This is all working code:

```
<?php

require_once 'jpgraph/jpgraph.php'; 
require_once 'jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php'; 
require_once 'jpgraph/jpgraph_plotline.php';        

$graph = new Graph(600,600); 
$graph->SetMargin(40, 10, 10, 0); 
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$this->graph->graph_theme=null;

$line = new LinePlot(range(5,25)); 
$line->SetWeight(1); 
$line->SetLegend("test"); 
$graph->Add($line);

$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(true);
$graph->title->hide();
$graph->xaxis->Hide();
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid"); 
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');
$graph->legend->hide();

$graph->Stroke();

?>
```